# 2D array in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I want to create mysql query:

```
"SELECT *, route.id as id_id, profile.id as profile_id 
FROM route_date LEFT JOIN route ON route_date.id_route = route.id 
LEFT JOIN profile ON route.user_id = profile.id  
WHERE route_date.date_time <= '$hike_date_to_input_updated' 
AND (route_date.date_time + INTERVAL (ROUND('$start[id_id][distance_route]'/route.route_distance*route.route_time)) SECOND) >='$hike_date_from_input_updated' AND route.free >= $hike_free 
AND route.status = '2' 
AND route.type ='1' AND route.id IN  (".implode(",",$searching_route_ids).")
ORDER BY route_date.date_time ASC"
```

Problem is in

```
route_date.date_time + INTERVAL (ROUND('$start[id_id][distance_route]'/route.route_distance*route.route_time)) SECOND) >='$hike_date_from_input_updated'.
```

I need to calculate +seconds if matching criteria for all ids in currently route.id(id_id) generating during this select and I have stored them in 2d array $start[id_id][distance_route] from previous calculations. How to achieve it?

Comment: It might be easier to format your query a bit, using the code-styles available (you can see a preview when you ask the question), and some newlines etc. This is hard to read.

Comment: "SELECT *, named.column" is just daft. Just name the columns you actually want returned. Also, a LEFT JOIN in combination with a WHERE clause (on the joined table) renders that OUTER JOIN as an INNER one.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter WHAT your query is, you retrieve the data from any select query in exactly the same basic way. Field names, table names, etc.. might change, but the you still use the same mechanics. Basically it boils down to

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

If you need to build a multi-dimensional array from your retrieved data, you'd do

```
    $data[$row['field1']][$row['field2']][...etc...] = $row;
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
           array key #1    array key #2    array keys 3..n
```

instead. Basically use individual values from the retrieved row as keys in your new array.

Comment: (but don't use a deprecated API)